# Como se envia un formulario con file y text?

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

en el siguiente código veréis que he echo un formulario para postear en un blog y un archivo php para guardarlo en la BBDD, no se porque pero ahora mismo tal y como esta no hace nada y no entiendo por que. hasta ahora solo he echo formularios que mandan files solo o texto solo pero con los dos en el mismo formulario no. a ver si alguien sabe solucionarlo.

Este es el archivo crear_blog.php: en este archivo solamente esta el html y el script encargado de POSTear el formulario hacia el archivo php/crear_blog.php (los archivo se llaman igual pero uno esta en la raiz y el otro esta dentro de la carpeta php)

```html
                <script>
                    $("form#blogform").submit(function(e){
                        e.preventDefault();
                        var formData = new formData(this);
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "php/crear_blog.php",
                            data: formData,
                            success: function(data) {
                                 $("#respuestaform").html(data);
                            },
                            cache: false,
                            contentType:false,
                            processData: false
                        });
                    });
                </script>
                <?php
                    print_r($_POST);
                    print_r($_FILES);
                ?>
                <form role="form" method="post" action="" name='blogform' id="blogform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>WEB</label>
                                <select class="form-control" name="web">
                                    <option value="Skootik">Skootik</option>
                                    <option value="AlchemyML">AlchemyML</option>
                                    <option value="Ambos">Ambos</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>TITULO</label>
                                <input class="form-control" name="titulo">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>SUBTITULO</label>
                                <input class="form-control" name="subtitulo">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
                        <div class="col-lg-2">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>FECHA</label>
                                <input id="startdate" name="fecha" type="date" min="2019-01-01">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>DESCRIPCION</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" rows="2" name="descripcion"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                                Subir imagen: <input type="file" name="file">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>YOUTUBE</label>
                                <input class="form-control" name="youtube">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-lg-1">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Enviar</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div id="respuestaform"style="text-align:center;"></div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

en el segundo archivo esta el php que recive los datos del form y los guarda en la BBDD y la parte que sube a una carpeta el file.

```php
<?php
    session_start();
    error_reporting(E_ERROR);
    if ($_POST['titulo']!='') {
        require('conexion.php');
        $titulo=$_POST['titulo'];
        $subtitulo=$_POST['subtitulo'];
        $descripcion=$_POST['descripcion'];
        $fecha=$_POST['fecha'];
        $file=$_POST['file'];
        $youtube =$_POST['youtube'];
        $web =$_POST['web'];
        if (isset($_FILES["file"])){
            $id=$_SESSION['identificador'];
            $file = $_FILES["file"];
            $nombre = $file["name"];
            $tipo = $file["type"];
            $ruta_provisional = $file["tmp_name"];
            $size = $file["size"];
            $dimensiones = getimagesize($ruta_provisional);
            $width = $dimensiones[0];
            $height = $dimensiones[1];
            $carpeta = "../img/blogs/";
            if ($tipo != 'image/jpg' && $tipo != 'image/jpeg' && $tipo != 'image/png' && $tipo != 'image/gif'){
                echo "Error, el archivo no es una imagen"; 
            }
            else if ($size > 1024*1024){
                echo "Error, el tamaño máximo permitido es un 1MB";
            }
            else if ($width > 500 || $height > 500){
                echo "Error la anchura y la altura maxima permitida es 500px";
            }
            else if($width < 60 || $height < 60){
                echo "Error la anchura y la altura mínima permitida es 60px";
            } else {
                $src = $carpeta.$nombre;
                move_uploaded_file($ruta_provisional, $src);
            }
        }
        mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO blogs (Titulo,Subtitulo,Descripcion,Fecha,Urlimg,Yt,Web) VALUES ('$titulo','$subtitulo','$descripcion','$fecha','$nombre','$youtube','$web')"); 
        echo '<div class="alert alert-success"><strong>BLOG REGISTRADO CORRECTAMENTE!</strong></div>';   
    }
    else {
        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger"><strong>Tienes que rellenar el campo NOMBRE DE LA EMPRESA</div>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Alguna pista de qué error te esta dando el PHP? podrías confirmar que las variables POST estén llegando correctamente?
Puedes habilitar errores en PHP con: 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

La consola del navegador da algún error?

Comment: Revisa el valor de `$_FILES['file']['error']`

Comment: si, lo he comprobado y da algun tipo de problema con la carpeta temp pero en otro script lo tengo exactamente igual pero con lo valores para ese proyecto y si que me funciona